# Is there a standard way to add dividers between action bar items in Android 3.0?

Tags: android, layout, menuitem, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

I have a slight problem trying to customise the look of the action bar in my app. I want to be able to have the pixel wide dividers to group action bar items that you see in many of the native apps (e.g. Gmail, Calendar). I found a way to do this by adding a menu item and setting the 'android:actionLayout' attribute to a custom layout for the divider:

```
<View
  android:background="@color/LightGray"
  android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
  android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
  android:layout_width="1dip"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

This works nicely, but the issue is it counts as a menu item and the action bar seems to limit the number of menu items to 4 - any others get pushed into the overflow menu.

So I guess what I'm asking is whether there is a standard way to add item dividers without having to use a menu item with a custom view, and in a way that doesn't count towards the limit for action bar items?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By "action bar" are you actually referring to the menu that appears when the user clicks the menu button?

Comment: Hi, sorry only just seen this comment. I'm referring to the tablet specific action bar that has been introduced in Honeycomb which by default uses the menu items but can be customised further which is what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wouldn't try and force dividers into places that the system does not add them automatically as it will make your app inconsistent with the platform.  The default behavior is:

- Divider between overflow and others.
- Divider between text and another item where it would disambiguate which item the text belongs to.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a standard way, but the way I did it was to use the `android:actionLayout` property for the menu item, and I put the divider in there.

Comment: Very useful pointer.  I created an XML layout with a TextView having both a drawableLeft of my icon and a drawableRight for my separator, then set drawablePadding to an aesthetically pleasing value. Worked like a charm.

Comment: @Chris: I had use android:actionLayout but its not working for me. I have added simple view in the layout with black color for the divider in the menu item bt its not working...Can you plz help me in tht?

Comment: I want the divider in one of the menu item..Its good to suggest any idea to implement..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When Google released the 3.0 SDK I got a quick demo app to see how the ActionBar works and just looking back at it, if I use Text Items without Icon drawables, then I get automatic dividers drawn.

My menu.xml file is like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_text" android:showAsAction="ifRoom" android:title="@string/action_label_text" />
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_text" android:showAsAction="ifRoom" android:title="@string/action_label_text" />
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_text" android:showAsAction="ifRoom" android:title="@string/action_label_text" />
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_text" android:showAsAction="ifRoom" android:title="@string/action_label_text" />
</menu>
```

Maybe this won't work with icons??

Or thinking about it, maybe the size of the icon has an effect?

Comment: give me any example and link for this one.

Comment: link for what? SDK samples?