# Adding dividers between items on an Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Simple question, I just cant find a definitive answer for this.

I have several menu options presented in a drop down list (items are given the showAsAction value: collapseActionView) the remaining action items are displayed as icons (items are given the showAsAction value: always).

I want to draw a divider between the icons which are always visible and the the overflow menu dropdown button.

If you look in the top right of this screen grab you can see it can be done - the divider appears between the drop down icon and other icons:
http://www.droid-life.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/screen_20111023_0800.png

I currently inflate my menu from an xml file, as explained here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910133/is-there-a-standard-way-to-add-dividers-between-action-bar-items-in-android-3-0