# Showing dividers between menu items in android actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, divider, android-actionbaractivity

I want show  dividers between menu items in android actionbar

Icon1 | Icon2 | icon3

my code for showing menu items is

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_time"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_time_btn_stateful"
    android:title="time"
    peel:showAsAction="always"/>
<item android:id="@+id/menu_room_change"
      android:icon="@drawable/action_room_btn_stateful"
      android:title="change"
      peel:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_like_set"
    android:icon="@drawable/like_button"
    android:title="Like"
    peel:showAsAction="always" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, 
your actionbar in ICS and later version is limited to show 4 items in menu.

The rest of the items can be shown when you tap on overflow menu (vertical 3 dotted line).

So adding a divider between items counts divider is also a menu item.

Did you take a look at these already :)

[Is there a standard way to add dividers between action bar items in Android 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910133/is-there-a-standard-way-to-add-dividers-between-action-bar-items-in-android-3-0)

[ActionBar MenuItem Divider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338867/actionbar-menuitem-divider)

I suggest get your icons with divider on their left or right based on your requirement.

Not a good practice. But let me know if you find a better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting custom style

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
<item name="android:background">@color/action_bar_background</item>
<item name="android:showDividers">beginning</item>
<item name="android:divider">@color/action_bar_divider</item>
</style>
```