# Sub Menu - titles/separators between some menu items

Tags: android, menu, submenu, divider

I would like to have a horizontal line or a customisable text as seperators between *a few* items in my sub menus, not between all. Does anyone know if and how this can be achieved? I tried using an action view, but that's not working.

I know, I can rewrite my menus and use custom popups, but I want to avoid that if possible. This would mean I would have to get rid of my menu xml files and can't use the convenient menu functions that already exists...

I tried something like following, but that's not working, as the action view is not rendered in sub menus directly:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:title="@string/action_more"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_vert_white_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="always">

        <menu>

            <group android:id="@+id/group1">

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/action1"
                    android:title="@string/action1"
                    android:icon="?ic_action1"
                    app:showAsAction="always" />

            </group>

            <!-- WOULD LIKE TO HAVE A LINE HERE OR CUSTOMISABLE TITLE -->

            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_sep"
                android:title=""
                app:showAsAction="always"
                android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_separator"
                android:enabled="false" />

            <group android:id="@+id/group2">

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/action2"
                    android:title="@string/action2"
                    android:icon="?ic_action2"
                    app:showAsAction="always" />

            </group>

        </menu>

    </item>

</menu>
```

**EDIT**

Current NOT BEAUTIFUL way (the seperator is just to high, I would like to make it 2dp high only or so):

```
menu.findItem(R.id.action_sep).setTitle(MenuUtil.getSeparatorText(menu.findItem(R.id.empty)));
```

With following functions:

```
public static String getSeparatorText(MenuItem menu)
{
    float maxWidth = getMaxWidthInSubMenu(menu);
    return getSeparatorText(menu, maxWidth );
}

private static float getMaxWidthInSubMenu(MenuItem menu)
{
    Paint p = new Paint();
    float maxLength = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < menu.getSubMenu().size(); i++)
    {
        String text = menu.getSubMenu().getItem(i).getTitle().toString();
        maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, p.measureText(text));
    }
    return maxLength;
}

private static String getSeparatorText(MenuItem menu, float maxWidth)
{
    Paint p = new Paint();
    // this is not a dash, but the box ascii character!
    // Combinations will look like a line: ──────────────────────────────
    String boxLine = "─"; 
    String sep = boxLine;
    while (p.measureText(sep) < maxWidth)
        sep += boxLine;
    return sep;
}
```

Comment: refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669708/showing-dividers-between-menu-items-in-android-actionbar

Comment: I'll edit my question... I don't need dividers between all items but between a few only, to group bigger menus...