# How to add divider in action bar items in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have three icons in action bar. Now I want to seperate them by a vertical line(like icon1 | icon2 | icon3) . How to add vertical line or divider in action bar between icons?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910133/is-there-a-standard-way-to-add-dividers-between-action-bar-items-in-android-3-0. Better use a toolbar with buttons and dividers between them.

Comment: check this also http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with those settings here:

```
<style name="Theme.Example" parent="Theme.Parent.Example">
    <item name="actionBarDivider">@drawable/small_detail_divider</item>
    ....
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@drawable/small_detail_divider</item>
    ...
</style>
```